# replication of document libraries in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, bcs, replication

In sharepoint 2010, Need to have a document library in a site and another document library in another site and the 2nd document library should be an exact copy of the 1st document library(with the doucments) in it. When 1st document library is updated with documents , 2nd document library should also populated with the changes made in document library 1. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create event receiver on document library Item added, where you can copy the current item into another Document Library with document.

another way is to have a Timer Job, which copies items of one document library to another and schedule it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2010 supports one way content replication through Content Deployment. But it works with site collection only. All site collection content will replicate to anothe site collection. But there are many 3d party solutions allow you to create more granular scenario. See here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/05/24/sharepoint-2010-replication-scenarios.aspx